# preg_replace regex stop at end of line

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Stuck on selecting and removing text using `preg_replace`. I have a starting point Address: with no end point, except that it does end with a new line. Is there a regex that will remove lines of text, using newline as your end point?

Address: 123 Main Street 
City: New York

`preg_replace('#Address:.*#si'), '', $lead_container)`

Above removes everything including City: New York which I am looking to keep. I could use City: as my end point, except that is not always available. Prefer newline `\n` as the endpoint.

`preg_replace('#Address:.*\n#si'), '', $lead_container)`

Tried adding `\n` and `\r` to my regex. That still selects everything. If it is possible, I sure would appreciate being pointed in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: Remove the `s` option, that will prevent `.` matching newline https://3v4l.org/qPlrN

Comment: That still removes everything after Address: need it to end Street using the newline as my endpoint.

Comment: It works fine in the demo link...

Comment: You could also make your regex non-greedy `echo preg_replace('#Address:.*?\n#si', '', $lead_container);` https://3v4l.org/V0T1R

Comment: My apologizes, it did work. I still had the \n in it. Your demo worked on this end. You rock! And thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of options. Firstly, you can remove the `s` option on your regex; that will prevent `.` matching newline:

```
echo preg_replace('#Address:.*#i', '', $lead_container);
```

Secondly, you can make the regex in your second example non-greedy by adding `?` after the `.*`:

```
echo preg_replace('#Address:.*?\n#si', '', $lead_container);
```

In both cases for sample input of

```
$lead_container = "Address: 123 Main Street
City: New York";
```

The output is `City: New York`. [Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/V0T1R)

Answer (score 0):

This starts to select after the first *blank*

```
preg_replace('[ ].*?\n', '', $lead_container)
```